# MVC .NET Core - Call a method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new to MVC.

I have a simple app that lists a number of links to websites, when each link is clicked I want to increment the "usage" integer.

```
public class Link
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Project { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public int Usage { get; set; }
    }
```

LinksController.cs includes all the CRUD functions, would I just add a new function in there and call it via jQuery Ajax?
I'm trying to use the "best practice" way rather than falling back to using something I would do in webforms so any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Search Google for jQuery ajax.  That is all that you need.

Comment: From where the links get clicked? Who clicks the links? Are they external pointing links or pointing you your application? How are you displaying the links?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to approach this, and AJAX isn't always necessary nor is it a magic wand to invoke server-side code.  Though you certainly *can* call an AJAX operation upon clicking the link.  You'd have to override the link's default behavior and invoke the AJAX operation, then redirect the user manually after the operation.  Another option is for each link to go to an action on your site with the target URL as a parameter.  That action can perform your server-side logic and then redirect the user to the target URL.

Comment: They are external links. Links are in various <a> tags within <divs>. I will read up on .ajax if that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link click happens client-side, so simply, you need some way to communicate back to the server when that happens to let it know. There's two possible approaches:

1. Have an endpoint on your server that records the link click and then redirects. Essentially you'd have a URL like `http://example.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com`. That bit at the end is just a standard URL that's been URL-encoded so it can be passed as a query string param. You don't really need to worry about that for the most part. If you use any of the Razor helpers to generate the link, they'll URL-encode it for you. Then, you have an action that responds to the `/redirect/` route, records the click in your database, and then redirects to `url`. Simple. However, this can be manipulated. For example, a user could simply take the `url` portion from the link and go there directly, bypassing your logic. You can mitigate this by not actually exposing the URL you're redirecting to, and instead, just referencing an id for the link in your database: `http://example.com/redirect?link=1234`, where `1234` would be the primary key for the link.
2. Use AJAX to notify the server. This is largely a similar process to the above: only you redirect client-side, rather than server-side, after you've received the server's response. However, since this happens client-side, it can be disabled or manipulated. You'll also be forced to expose the final destination URL this way, so a motivated user could dig through your source and get the URL to bypass any recording of the "click". Nevertheless, the process is fairly straight-forward:

   ```
   $('.redirect').on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var $link = $(this);
       $.ajax({
           url: '/path/to/action/that/records/click',
           method: 'POST',
           data: { url: $link.attr('href') },
           success: function () {
               location.href = $link.attr('href');
           })
       });
   });
   ```

One further note. Any time you're talking about incrementing some column in a database based on a request being made, you need to consider concurrency. Web servers are multi-threaded and handle many simultaneous requests. You're going to need to watch out for click counts being incremented on the same link at the same time. See [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) from MSDN for more information about what you'll need to do.